# Is this a valid use case for "ask" with regard to akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm reading http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/27/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-14-the-actor-approach-to-concurrency.html and in it, is declared :

> "Sometimes, sending an actor a message and expecting a message in
>   return at some later time isn’t an option – the most common place
>   where this is the case is in components that need to interface with
>   actors, but are not actors themselves. Living outside of the actor
>   world, they cannot receive messages.
>
> For situations such as these, there is Akka’s ask support, which
>   provides some sort of bridge between actor-based and future-based
>   concurrency. "

When does this situation apply, ie when to use Akka ask support ?
I'm using akka to create Actor requests that in turn create web service requests so I think this is a use case as I may not get a valid web service response in appropriate time frame. Also web service requests do not live in the Akka world. Am I correct in my reasoning ? What are the real world example where I should ask instead of tell ?

Comment: You can build a system like you are talking about w/o using ask at all.  Say you have an endpoint that based on an async capable web request fires a request to an endpoint servicing actor using tell, passing a context that allows the request to be completed.  This actor in turn tells to another actor for fetching of some data.  This data fetching actor tells back to the endpoint servicing actor who then completes the web request with the data sent back to it.  All w/o needing ask.

Comment: @cmbaxter but what if the request fails ? Should I restart the actor ?

Comment: @cmbaxter "This data fetching actor tells back to the endpoint servicing actor" how does this work since "tell" returns of type Unit ? What is the mechanism for telling back to the endpoint ?

Comment: The data fetcher will keep track of the sender of the request to fetch the data, which will be the endpoint handling actor.  When done fetching the data, it will tell back to that sender (the endpoint actor) with the response when it's done, returning control of that request to the endpoint actor who can then complete the request